# could not find the *.apk Error

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors, apk

```
[2011-06-22 23:55:09 - main] Android Launch!
[2011-06-22 23:55:09 - main] adb is running normally.
[2011-06-22 23:55:09 - main] Could not find main.apk!
```

I am new to Android development and stuck in a very strange error. When I compile my Android application  I get the above error. While before yesterday the application work nicely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's important to tag posts related to generic IDEs with the platform you're trying to develop for. This will attract developers with experience in using the IDE *with* the platform. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 7):

I hit this issue because I had accidentally made the project a library, by ticking the `Is library` checkbox @ `<your project>->right click->Properties->Android`

Comment: This is unpredictable problem which i also faced.Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Faced same problem, and could able to resolve by right clicking the project and then selecting Android Tools -> Fix Project properties and do a clean build. This answer may be come too late for this post but it could help others.

Answer (score 5):

I've been having the same problem.  It turns out that when you build your Android project Eclipse doesn't warn you if you don't have the Android SDK Build-tools installed - it just fails silently.

To further add to the problem, when I checked for updates in Eclipse (as many people had suggested) it opened the Android SDK Manager for me, but it didn't show the Android SDK Build-tools in the list!

However, if you open Eclipse and go to "Window->Android SDK Manager" then it will open the manager and should show that the Android SDK Build-tools are not installed.

Installing the Android SDK Build-tools and updating the other packages fixed the problem for me.  You may want to clean and rebuild all of your projects after the install.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem could be that you removed/renamed the main.apk file from /bin folder from your project folder. In this case, just make a small change on your code and compile again. A new .apk will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your build contains compile time error because .apk file is made after successful compilation